# How to set and unset cookies using AlpineJS and Tailwind Toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have the following code that uses tailwindcss for the toggle, and AlpineJS for adding a cookie base on the toggle state (on/off).

But I can't seem to make it work.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/williamharvey/pen/GRMBqzO

Any help or direction will be appreciated

Thanks

And here's the code.

```
<div 
class="flex w-full items-center bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200 px-5 py-3 text-sm"
x-data="{ cookieConcent1: docCookies.getItem('cookieConcent1') === 'true'} "
x-init="$watch('!cookieConcent1', val => docCookies.setItem('cookieConcent1', val))"
x-bind:class="{ 'cookieConcent1': cookieConcent1 }">
  <div class="flex-1">
    <p>Strictly necessary cookies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w-10 text-right">
    <button type="button" 
        class="relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-300 bg-gray-200" 
        x-data="{ on: true }" 
        role="switch" 
        aria-checked="false" 
        :aria-checked="on.toString()" 
        @click="on = !on;cookieConcent1 = !cookieConcent1"
        x-state:on="Enabled" 
        x-state:off="Not Enabled" 
        :class="{ 'bg-green-400': on, 'bg-gray-200': !(on) }
    ">
          <span class="sr-only">Use setting</span>
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200 translate-x-0" 
            x-state:on="Enabled" 
            x-state:off="Not Enabled" 
            :class="{ 'translate-x-5': on, 'translate-x-0': !(on) }
          "></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working for me (btw you have an unnecessary `!` before `cookieConcent1` inside `$watch`), I can see the value of `cookieConcent1` toggles between true/false after the click. Do you see any errors in the borwser's console? If you have [Alpin.js DevTools](https://github.com/alpine-collective/alpinejs-devtools) installed, do you see that values of `on` and `cookieConcent1` are changing after click?

Comment: @Dauros Thanks for the reply. You are right and it does work. And many thanks for the AlpineJS DEv tools tip, I didn't know about that. I now have another problem that I'll start a new post. Thank you!